# System.IO.File.Create locking a file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using `System.IO.File.Create` to create a file. I'm not writing to it with a stream writer, just creating it.

I get a server error in the front end when the application tries to open the newly created file - that the file is in use. Garbage collection then seems to come along and a few minutes later all is OK.

Now I know if I was using Streamwriter I would have to close it. Does the same apply to creating?

I've read that opening a stream writer to the file then immediately closing it will fix this, but it seems messy. Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

`File.Create` returns a `FileStream`. You should use it like this:

```
using (FileStream fs = File.Create(path))
{
    //you can use the filstream here to put stuff in the file if you want to
}
```

Comment: I'd have never ever expected that.

Comment: Yes, we all thought so. But the using statement does not work, not even if I put in fs.Close() at the end. The file still hangs. I am using .NET 4.6.1

Answer (score 122):

Try this:

```
System.IO.File.Create(FullFName).Close();
```

Comment: This is perfect for when you just want to create a blank file.

Comment: That is so true! "I'm not writting to it with a stream writer, just creating it".

Comment: This was what I was looking for as well. Works a charm with a blank file. Thanks.

Comment: Not a biggy, but this violates the disposable pattern. I would replace Close() with Dispose() (which also calls Close).

Comment: "I would replace `Close()` with `Dispose()`" or better yet, with a `using` statement

Answer (score 12):

Creating the file opens a `FileStream` to it, hence, locking it (`File.Create` returns the `FileStream`).

You must close this stream in order to access the file. This is best done with a `using` statement:

```
using(FileStream fs = File.Create(path))
{
}
```

Answer (score 9):

When using `File.Create` you get a `FileStream` returned. Until you either close the stream or until the `FileStream` object is disposed (by the garbage collector's finaliser) it will remain open and locked.

`FileStream` implements `IDisposable` so you can do the following:

```
using(FileStream fs = File.Create(filename))
{
    // Do stuff like write to the file
}
```

The `using` statement is "syntactic sugar" and causes the compiler to generate code that is functionally equivalent to:

```
FileStream fs = File.Create(filename)
try
{
    // Do stuff like write to the file
}
finally
{
    fs.Dispose();
}
```

The `Dispose` method calls `Close` internally.

Answer (score 3):

I was using:
`System.IO.File.Create(sFullFileName);`

The above `.Create` method was not closing the file

I now use:
`System.IO.File.WriteAllText(sFullFileName, "Uploading");`

This method creates and closes the file (note: I put a string "Uploading" in the file, but i'm sure `string.Empty` will also work.

Answer (score 1):

The `Create` method will return a file handle. The file handle should be closed before re-using the file. Please see details in the MSDN article *[File.Create Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03.aspx)*.

Summary:

> The FileStream object created by this method has a default FileShare value of None; no other process or code can access the created file until the original file handle is closed.