# Empty Text File in SSIS Package

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

In my Project, I want to create one empty text file when the package triggered.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd probably just use a one-line `Script task.`

```
System.IO.File.Create(@"C:\OneEmptyTextFile.txt");
```

1. On your Control Flow, drag a Task of type `Script Task` from your SSIS Tool Box
2. Double click on the new `Script Task`
3. In the Script Task Editor, click `Edit Script...`
4. In the `public void Main()` section, where it states `// TODO: Add your code here` replace that line with the above code. If you are using SSIS 2005 or if you have chosen to use VB.NET in 2008/2012, please remove the trailing semicolon.
5. Click the X button in the upper right corner of the Integration Services Script Task window
6. Back in the Script Task Editor, click `OK`.

Now whenever that Task runs, it will use the static [Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03.aspx) method of the File object to create a file in the requested location.

Comment: Thanks for sharing but could you please elaborate more about it, I am new to Script task.

Answer (score 0):

It might be good idea to dispose of the `FileStream` object after using the `File.Create` method to avoid locking issues.

Read more here [System.IO.File.Create locking a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680284/system-io-file-create-locking-a-file)