# Creating a new Text Document from DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, text-files

I've been trying to export my data from my DataGridView into a text file, it only works when I already have a txt doc, but I want it to auto generate new ones after every button click. Help would be appreciated. This is similar to what I have now:

```
TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\folder\Text.txt");
for(int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1; i++)
{
     for(int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
     {                        
          writer.Write("\t"+dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString()+"\t"+"|");
     }
     writer.WriteLine("");
     writer.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------------");
}
 writer.Close();
 MessageBox.Show("Data Exported");
```

It works now, thanks for the help. Anyone interested here's the code:

```
string datetime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MMMM-dddd-HH-mm-ss");
        string filePath = $@"C:\folder\{datetime}.txt";

        TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath);
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                writer.Write("\t" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString() + "\t" + "|");
            }
            writer.WriteLine("");
            writer.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------------");
        }
        writer.Close();
        //MessageBox.Show("Data Exported");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating text file in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27823789/creating-text-file-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to make some kind of unique name for your file. So do something like the below, where you use something (it's up to you what) like a DateTime string.

```
string datetime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HHMM");
string filePath = $@"C:\folder\Text{datetime}.txt";
File.Create(filePath);
TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path);
for(int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1; i++)
{
     for(int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
     {                        
          writer.Write("\t"+dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString()+"\t"+"|");
     }
     writer.WriteLine("");
     writer.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------------");
}
 writer.Close();
 MessageBox.Show("Data Exported");
```

Have a look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file?view=netframework-4.7.2) around File. There are lots of examples on how one should work with files.

Comment: In the 4th line of text, did you mean new StreamWriter(path) or new StreamWriter(filePath). When i used i got the error that the textfile is being used by another process.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't test it, but was trying to get the concept across more than write the exact code you needed. I take it it helped though?

Comment: Yes i just had to edit some lines but other than that it worked, thanks allot mate.

Answer (score 0):

You can create before this code your own text file like this:

```
string path = "C:\folder\Text.txt";
if (!File.Exists(path))
{
    File.Create(path);
}
```

with file exist you can check if the file already exists, if not then create it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `File.WriteAllText`

```
string path = "C:\folder\Text"
for(int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
{
File.WriteAllText(path + j + ".txt", yourTextToWrite);
}
```

It will generate new file if .txt file is not existing.

To prepare `yourTextToWrite` you can use `StringBuilder` class:

```
StringBuilder yourTextToWrite = new StringBuilder();
yourTextToWrite.Append("text1\n");
yourTextToWrite.Append("text2\n");
```